# Python. Поднять регистр слов в строке

Tags: python, строки, циклы

Сижу над кодом. Вроде сделал правильно, но где-то есть ошибка и программа не делает то, что должна.
Задание: Задано текст, сделать программу которая определяет и поднимает регистр тех слов, в которых согласных меньше, чем гласных
Мой код:

```
text="ііі ввв ііі"
lst=text.split()
print(lst)
vowels = 0
consonants = 0
for i in lst:
    letter = i.lower()
    if letter == "а" or letter == "е" or\
        letter == "и" or letter == "і" or\
        letter == "о" or letter == "у":
        vowels += 1
    else:
        consonants += 1
        if vowels > consonants:
            i.upper()
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно так попробовать:

считаем кол-во гласных букв и сравниваем их с размером слова (должно быть больше половины)

```
result = [w.upper() if len([l for l in w.lower() if l in 'аеиіоу']) > len(w) // 2 else w for w in text.split()]
```

вариант 2:

```
result = [(w, w.upper())[len([l for l in w.lower() if l in 'аеиіоу']) > len(w) // 2] for w in text.split()]
```

вариант 3 (спасибо @Danis):

```
result = [(w, w.upper())[sum(l in "aеиіоу" for l in w.lower()) > len(w) // 2] for w in text.split()]
```

Comment: `len([l for l in w.lower() if l in 'аеиіоу'])` можно записать так:`sum(l in "aеиіоу" for l in w.lower())`

Comment: да, действительно лучше через сумму, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```
text = "ііі ввв ііі"
lst = text.split()
print(lst)

for i in range(len(lst)):
    a, b = 0, 0
    for letter in lst[i].lower():
        if letter in ["а", "е", "и", "і", "о", "у"]:
            a += 1
        else:
            b += 1
    if a > b:
        lst[i] = lst[i].upper()

print(lst)
```